# change max steepness of slope character can climb godot

Tags: godot

I am making a platformer game with all the basic code that is usualy found in godot platformers(kinimaticbody2d,move_and_slide, etc). the problem is that the character can climb really steep slopes which I dont like.

for example the character can move up the slope shown in the picture simply by pressing left(no jumping) he just slowly slides up
[image]

but when i make the slope just a little bit steeper the character cant scale the slope.
[image]

my  question is there a way to set the maximum angle of a slope that a character can climb? thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [`move_and_slide`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_kinematicbody2d.html#class-kinematicbody2d-method-move-and-slide) you need to:

- Specify an `up_direction` vector, which goes into the second parameter of `move_and_slide`. Without it, everything is considered a wall, and no sliding happens. *Since, you are experiencing sliding, I suspect you already have this.*
- And specify `floor_max_angle` float, which goes into the fifth parameter of `move_and_slide`. This controls how inclined can be a surface and still be considered a floor/slope. If a surface is more steep that this angle, it will be considerad a wall, and no sliding happens. The angle is measured between the normal of the surface and the `up_direction` vector provided.

By default the value of `floor_max_angle` is `0.785398` (it is in radians, by the way) which is equivalent to 45º.

The situation you are suggest you are using a number closer to a quarter turn (i.e π/2 - approx `1.57` - radians). *Probably something like 1.2 or 1.3?* You want a smaller value.

*By the way, you can convert from radians to degrees with [`rad2deg`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_@gdscript.html#class-gdscript-method-rad2deg) and viceversa with [`deg2rad`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_@gdscript.html#class-gdscript-method-deg2rad).*

---

I'll quickly go over a couple more issues you may find along the way:

- The character slides down when idle due to gravity. To prevent this, you want to set `stop_on_slope` to true. This is the third parameter of `move_and_slide`.
- The character have jitter and move more than desired when going down the slope with user input (caused by very little jumps usually perceived as jitter). And this is why you would want to [`move_and_slide_with_snap`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_kinematicbody2d.html#class-kinematicbody2d-method-move-and-slide-with-snap), which has an extra `snap` vector parameter which allows you to specify a direction the character should stick to the ground while moving. By the way, you may want to use [`get_slide_collision`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_kinematicbody2d.html#class-kinematicbody2d-method-get-slide-collision) to figure out on what surface the character did slide, if any, and what is its normal.